# how to convert pandas dataframe convert string array to array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, python-3.6

I am going to read a csv file and send to json stream format. 
One of the coulmn is in array format but in pandas dataframe it will return string format. 
How cany I convert "attributes_changed" column from string array to normal array format?

**Sample Code:**

```
import json
import pandas as pd

sample = {"event_id": "dd9726c4-9c22-47b3-9a1b-fd6ecf494076", "event_type": "UPDATED", "attributes_changed": "[\'metadataStatus\', \'elements\']"}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=sample, index=[0])

df_with_seq_id = [(json.dumps(rec), idx) for (idx, rec) in df.to_dict(orient='index').items()]
```

**Current Result**

> [('{"event_id": "dd9726c4-9c22-47b3-9a1b-fd6ecf494076", "event_type": "UPDATED", "attributes_changed": **"['metadataStatus', 'elements']"**}', 0)]

**Expected Result** (Removed double quotes)

> [('{"event_id": "dd9726c4-9c22-47b3-9a1b-fd6ecf494076", "event_type": "UPDATED", "attributes_changed": **['metadataStatus', 'elements']**}', 0)]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply apply `eval` on column `attributes_changed` to interpret the string values as an array:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

sample = {
    "event_id": "dd9726c4-9c22-47b3-9a1b-fd6ecf494076",
    "event_type": "UPDATED",
    "attributes_changed": "['metadataStatus', 'elements']",
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=sample, index=[0])
df["attributes_changed"] = df["attributes_changed"].apply(eval)
df_with_seq_id = [
    (json.dumps(rec), idx) for (idx, rec) in df.to_dict(orient="index").items()
]
```

This produce the following array:

```
[('{"event_id": "dd9726c4-9c22-47b3-9a1b-fd6ecf494076", "event_type": "UPDATED", "attributes_changed": ["metadataStatus", "elements"]}',
  0)]
```

Comment: This is streaming data, so I am not sure about column name. Is there any way to do this in generic way without using column name?